# intel virtualisation enabled on bios but hyper v not running

Tags: visual-studio, windows-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

ive got a sony vaio duo 13.

ive gone into bios using the assist key and enabled intel virtualisation tech setting. The emulator stll doesn't work.

all programs run from this site have returned that it supports hyper v but that it is not turned on?any ideas?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj863509(v=vs.105).aspx

[image]

[image]

Comment: why the minus? if you tell me what's wrong with the question I can make it better, don't go knock me down before stating why!

Comment: James, your question is off-topic for StackOverflow. This question would be better suited for SuperUser.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was not exactly obvious. After reading everywhere about intel trust execution needing to be disabled, I decided to attempt to disable anything to do wit bitlocer. On my specific hybrid, there was a setting labelled "secure boot mode", there were a few options here but I tried to just disable it. Hey presto that was the sucker. I hope this helps someone else.

**Edit::**

Above answer was actually incorrect. If you change the bios setting on my laptop, then shutdown and start up. nothing happens. if you then restart the computer a whole load of hardware fails, butttt intel VT works finally lol. It must have been dumb luck it worked before. But the shutdown/restart combo works predictably. Unfortunately it totally knocks out some of my other hardware (touchscreen, key lights) rendering this entirely freaking useless :(